# Is "How do I copy (part of) site X", an appropriate type of question?

Tags: discussion, questions

Questions like the following ones are, in my opinion, not appropriate to ask at all.

- How do I create a slideshow like this one: [LINK TO ARBITRARY SITE]?
- How do I create [RANDOM BEHAVIOUR] like [LINK TO OTHER SITE]?

One should clearly define the desired functionalty in a way that is completely independant of external resources. I would even go so far as to suggest that even after the question has been written properly, it is wrong to do

"Examples of above mentioned functionality can be seen [HERE][1]."

Reason being that the site being linked to may change entirely with a very short timeframe, or just go away all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions and answers should stand alone, which means they should be understandable without any reference to external sites, or without links to other questions/answers given in the same Stack Exchange site.

As posts on Stack Exchange sites must be useful to any future reader, and not only to the OP who asked the question, the posts should be written in a way that, even in the case the used links are not valid anymore, it still possible to understand what they are saying.
In the cases you reported, the OP should describe the functionality, and eventually add a screenshot taken from a site that already has the required functionality, or a picture showing the mock-up of the required feature. Stack Exchange has a pro account on [Imgur](http://imgur.com/), and Stack Exchange makes a backup of the pictures saved in that account. This means that [the images added to a post using the functionality offered from the post editor are kept indefinitely](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/), and in the case something happens, [Stack Exchange has backups](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124989/140449).